# Summing values if same second column value

Tags: text-processing

With Unix script, I'd like to add values in column 1 if text in column 2 is the same and print the sum. 
I have a file that is:

```
7 GeneA
2 GeneB
6 GeneC
2 GeneB
9 GeneA
```

I want the output to look like:

```
16 GeneA
4  GeneB
6  GeneC
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Use **awk** script:

```
awk '{ a[$2]+=$1 }END{ for(i in a) print a[i],i }' file
```

- `a[$2]+=$1` - accumulating values for each group(*"group"* is considered as unique value of the 2nd field, used as array `a` index)

The output:

```
16 GeneA
4 GeneB
6 GeneC
```

Answer (score 7):

With GNU [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)  command.

```
datamash groupby 2 sum 1 <infile.txt
```

Comment: ++ , cause I like `datamash`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using Perl:

```
perl -aE '$F{$F[1]}+=$F[0];END {say "$F{$_} $_" for keys %F}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Google Crush Tools](https://github.com/google/crush-tools)' `subtotal`:

```
$ sort --key 2 yourFile.txt | subtotal --key 2 --sum 1 --delim ' '

7 GeneA
9 GeneA
16 

2 GeneB
2 GeneB
4 

6 GeneC
6
```